# Why is php adding a <pre> tag at the end of my html?

Tags: php, html

Me = superBeginner

MyActivity = testing communication between php and my sql database hosted on Azure.(1st time)

MyQuestion = $title

HTMLOutputDesired:
[web page screenshot showing what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABhzH.png)

HTMLCurrentOutput:
[web page screenshot showing what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xX9J.png)

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test connection</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php



$serverName = "lunch.database.windows.net"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"LunchProgramBE", "UID"=>"lunch", 
"PWD"=>"*****");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$sql = "Select * from Meals";
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

if( $query === false) {
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)){

echo $row[0] . ", " . $row[1] . "<br>";

}



sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);
sqlsrv_close( $conn );
?>

</body>
</html>
```

If I add this line before the while statement, it works properly... (?)

```
echo "<br>";
```

When inspecting the page using chrome, I see that php is adding a pre tag to the end of the html file. This pre tag holds the last item in the list. WHY???

```
<pre>1, Turkey, V8</pre>
```

HTML output for bad case: [bad case HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSclc.png)

HTML output for good case: [good case HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPupk.png)

Comment: Are you sure it's not stored in the DB that way?

Comment: PHP isn't adding any `<PRE>` tags. They are elsewhere in your code, or the data in your database.

Comment: No, if I test with the br tag added it shows it in the correct order. Also, why the pre tag anyway?? Even if it was...

Comment: I am familiar with database design (I'm not a programmer but do develop on MS Access and VBA and SQL Server). I'm sure the database contains only simple data.. no tags..

Comment: The image I show for what I'm looking for is actually what I'm getting through HTML by adding the br tag. Also, no pre tags show up in this case...

Comment: Post the entirety of the HTML output for both cases.

Comment: OK added HTML output to my post..

Comment: What do you get from your database when you run this query: Select * from Meals

Comment: In Chrome, do you still see the `<pre>` tag output if instead of using the (dynamic) web inspector, you choose "View Source" from the Developer menu? I'm wondering if some bit of JavaScript or possibly Chrome's own broken-DOM-tidying is creating the problem.

Comment: When I run that query in Access I get the rows in the order I expect. I can also view the table directly and see that they are in that order. The first column is the ID. Even if the data was wrong, why would it change when I add the break tag?

Comment: view source gives me this: 
1, Turkey, V8<br>2, Ham, Apple Juice<br>3, Steak, Coke<br>4, Salad, OJ<br>5, Cheeseburger, Fries, 7UP<br>

Comment: @CShore Bear in mind that databases, including Access, don't guarantee ordering of their results unless you specify an ORDER BY clause. It would be perfectly okay by database rules if Access returned a different order to different clients, or a different order every time you ran that query, without an ORDER BY.

Comment: So no pre tags in source actually...

Comment: it's not really the order actually that concerns me as much as the formatting applied by pre and the extra space.

Comment: So, one of two things must be happening, I think: either your HTML is malformed, and Chrome is tidying it up when building the DOM and somehow thinks you need a `<pre>` tag (unlikely) or some piece of JavaScript on the page itself or loaded through a Chrome extension is adding it.

Comment: Could it be because I haven't built the proper HTML structure (i.e. title, head, body etc)?

Comment: adding the break tag maybe just signifies to chrome that this is html and then formats everything properly from there? Without the break tag, the first thing it sees are just characters...

Comment: Possibly; yes. That's my first option above. But we'd need to see the complete, real page source before we can start working out what's going on. Basically, a browser needs a valid Document Object Model to render a page. If you send it a page of broken HTML source, it'll do its best to fix it up, and when you use the Web Inspector, you're viewing the DOM after the fixing. You're also seeing it after any Chrome extensions you have loaded have mangled the page however they want, too...

Comment: Try to wrapp each line to p tag for example to see what will happen. And remove br at the end

Comment: (First thing to try is to use at least a basic (HTML5, most probably) page structure to wrap around your code to make it a real HTML page when the browser sees it.)

Comment: OK, added all the proper HTML tags and still same thing. Matt, I did give you the page source output above (sorry not formatted but is exactly what was coming from page source... 1 line)

Comment: Modified code above to include HTML tags that I'm now using...

Comment: What do you see if you try the same thing from a Chrome window in Incognito mode? (File->New Incognito Window)?

Comment: Ahh... then it works....what??

Comment: After adding proper HTML tags, page source shows a normal looking HTML document. When I copy past that into a new HTML file and open it, it looks the way it should... just not when going through PHP...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you're not sending the `<pre>` tag, which we can tell by doing View Source, then the only explanations I can think of are:

1. Chrome is adding it in some strange attempt to make an invalid HTML document into a valid DOM in memory, or
2. You have a Chrome extension installed that's putting the `<pre>` element there.

The former seems unlikely as you've altered your source to be valid HTML and you're still seeing the problem.

As you've now found that the problem disappears in Incognito mode, which disables extensions by default, it seems most likely that one of your Chrome extensions is actually adding the `<pre>` tag for some reason. Go through them until you find the culprit and you might be able to figure out why...

Comment: Matt, thanks so much for helping on this ambiguous issue... will look into that. By the way, I am running on a local server through WAMP if it makes a difference or gives you any other ideas as well...

Comment: Went through 1 by 1 and found the culprit: JSON Viewer!! When disabled, everything looks as it should... SO FRUSTRATING!!! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: for me it was jsonviewer extension too. Thanks mate